# In pandas, I would like to replace the values of a column in a df, with values found in a corresponding dictionary

Tags: pandas

Thanks in advance.

I read in the initial csv and narrowed down the file to a 35 column dataframe. One of the columns is comprised of integers that function as keys in another dictionary. I read in that dictionary by manually pulling it out of an excel file and saving it as it's own csv that I read in. The keys are currently the index but I can change that.

sidenotes: -2 = Not applicabe, -1 = Not reported, 22 is the first value, values such as 23, 25, 26, 29, 31, 32, and so on missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pandas.Series.map](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) method. We suppose you have a python dictionary with the categories, for example:

```
categories = {
    -1: 'Not aplicable',
    -2: 'Not reported',
    -3: 'Another category',
     ...
     63: 'Value 63'
}

#Sample data
your_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Fullname', 'key'], data=[["John","Dow",-1], ["Someone","ELse",-2]])

# Now you can use map method on the `key` you want mapping
your_dataframe['key'] = your_dataframe['key'].map(categories)
your_dataframe
```

Output:

```
     Name   Fullname    key
0   John    Dow     Not aplicable
1   Someone ELse    Not reported
```

Answer (score 1):

If the number of keys is low enough, I would suggest making a function like:

```py
def categorizer(row):
    if row == -2:
        return 'Not applicable'
    elif row == -1:
        return 'Not reported'
    ...
    else:
        return 'Key'

df['key'] = df['key'].apply(categorizer)
```

Comment: There are 63 values.